# How to run a pipeline only on changes in a specific branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am looking through the documentation back and forth and cannot find how to configure my `.gitlab-ci.yml` so that the content is executed only on a change in the branch `mqtt_based` and not in the default `master`.

I was hoping that adding an `only` entry for each section would be enough (I was hoping for a global setting), but this did not help (the pipeline was not started when the `mqtt_based` branch was changed)

```
variables:
  BRANCH: "mqtt_based"

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job:build-back:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd back
    - docker build --build-arg COMMIT=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} --build-arg DATE=$(date --iso-8601=seconds) -t registry.XXX/homemonitor-back:latest -t registry.XXX/homemonitor-back:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} -f Dockerfile .
  only:
    - $BRANCH
(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 'refs' after 'only'. Something like this

```
only:
  refs:
    - mqtt_based
```

Documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced

Comment: Thanks. Should adding this to the jobs be enough to run them? I did that and the branch is not built. The "build" logo (circle with progress or checkmark) is only present on `master`.

Comment: That should be sufficient. I'm not sure why your build didn't work on mqtt_based... That's odd.